# Are layout ids unique for a given application (project including its libraries) or just the given project?

Tags: java, android, view, android-resources

Can view ids be passed into a library and be expected to point to the item in the non-library project containing the library? I have an adapter class which is going to be distributed to third party developers. I want to provide them with a custom adapter, which deals with our own abstract data type for messages, but is flexible enough to use differently styled views that would be passed in on creation via a view id; there exist alternatives to the following, but generally developers like to use what they are used to (ie the ArrayAdapter). So, my question is: will ids for a layout (ie the integer R.layout.a_text_view), point to the correct resource from the third party project if passed from a third party project into a library that has its own layouts in the res folder? Thank you for any guidance on how far the scope of resource ids extend.

Edit:
After looking around a little more, I noticed that the library project essentially becomes a part of the project as a whole, but then my question is the following: if multiple resources exist with the same name, but in the R of either com.third.party.R or com.library.R (example package names), where do they become ids, at compile time, or at runtime, and how unique are the ids? Is accessing a resource in the library from the main application possible given the package name of R, and is it possible to pass resource ids from one to another as int parameters in code? Thanks in advance for setting me straight!